# PHP Mysql configuration throws dll error on Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql

while running the php command it throws the below error

```
c:\> php -v
```

[image: ql]

```
php.ini file

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir ="C:\PHP\ext"
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Comment: how do you install php ? Is it the post-install behavior ?

Comment: @w00d i installed php-5.2.17-Win32-VC6-x86 then added extension folder and the dll files in the class path.

Comment: so does it work without the extensions?

Comment: @w00d yes without extension no issue encounterd.

Comment: Then you may want to narrow it down, find the extension that causes the problem. You can disable all then enable each of them one by one until the problem occurs.

Comment: @anish Why don't you simply install WAMP/XAMPP ?